# Jquery EasyUI tabs Append Webpart

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have sharepoint online and I am trying to create a script that takes webparts on a page and puts them into tabs. The solution doesn't need to be dynamic. I asked another question on this, and got a good start, but I am confused on why it isn't working/ where to go from here. My current code is as follows:

```
        <!---->
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://x.sharepoint.com/sites/project_sb3/SiteAssets/dev_jqueryui/themes/default/easyui.css">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://x.sharepoint.com/sites/project_sb3/SiteAssets/dev_jqueryui/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://x.sharepoint.com/sites/project_sb3/SiteAssets/dev_jqueryui/jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>

            <script>
            //IDs of webparts to add
            var tabs = ['<id MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ12>', '<id MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ13>'];

            ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(initTabs, "sp.js");

            func initTabs(){
                //hide all of the webparts
                for(var i=0;i<tabs.length;i++){
                $('#' + tabs[i]).hide();
                }

                //show the first webpart in tab 1

            }

            //show the webpart of the clicked tab
            function clickTab(id){
                for(var i=0;i<tabs.length;i++){
                    if(tabs[i] === id){
                         $('#' + id).show(); 
                    }else{
                         $('#' + tabs[i]).hide();
                    }
                }
            }
            </script>

            <div class="easyui-tabs" style="width:1200px;height:1000px">
                <div title="Project Documents" style="padding:10px" onclick="clickTab('<id MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ12>')">

                </div>

                <div title="Project Updates" style="padding:10px" onclick="clickTab('<id MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ13>')">

                </div>
            </div>
        <!---->
```

As I understand it, the above code should hide the two webparts in the 'Tabs' array, then when it loads it shows the first webpart. When a tab is clicked, the other tab's webpart is hidden and the new one should be shown.

This code is not working, and I am wondering if it is because I am not moving the webparts. I hide/show them but I don't add them as children to the tab's zones. If that is the fix, I'm not quite sure how to go about it.